Macbook air 2017 is responding very slowly
I have a Macbook Air 2017 and it became very slow after I installed Monterey in August 2022.
I reinstalled macOS twice and also formatted the disk completely. There is no overheating issue at all, but still the CPU% is very high. Only less than 5-10% CPU is free, which is making my mac very slow. I don't even have any apps right now in my system as I have formatted the entire system. The MacBook has 120 GB of space available, but still mac is responding very slow.
I have also reset SMC, NVRAM, verified disk multiple times, with no effect on the performance. I have already checked while in safe mode, but this has no effect. Please help if anyone has faced similar issue ?

Safe Mode is a diagnostic mode, not something that fixes problems.  Boot into Diagnostic Mode. Boot your Mac while holding the 'D' key.  Start from there and let's see if we can figure out what the issue is.

I have a couple 2017 machines that became unbearable with the more recent MacOS versions.  The fix was to get an external SSD and boot up from that instead.  Good as new.

@TomGewecke 2017 was just when APFS was introduced, so a problem with the internal disk might be some sort of 'legacy' issue on the internal drive from the transition. But the OP says they've erased the disk. Though hard to know whether they've actually erased and reinstalled the EFI & Recovery containers, etc.

Reinstalling the OS itself is usually never a solution; but by erasing the disk and reinstalling the OS you have ruled out any third-party software and user settings -- though there are easier ways of doing that.
Reinstalling the OS a second time won't install anything differently.
Can you see what in Activity Monitor is using all the CPU % ...? What makes you sure it's not overheating? If kernel_task is high, that could be trying to prevent overheating. (A failed sensor might send high values.)
Assuming it's not a software problem (on a clean disk), then that leaves us with hardware. You can try Diagnostic mode, though really there's no substitute for taking it to an Apple Store or other authorized repair shop.
